# Undertow virtual host omits default application context

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, wildfly-10, undertow

I have two domains pointing to two deployments in the same Wildfly instance.
My goal is, typing one or another in the browser, the server redirects to the specific .war file.

Currently, my configuration at `standalone.xml` is:

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
    <host name="app1" alias="app1.mydomain.com" default-web-module="app1.war">
       <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
       <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
    <host name="app2" alias="app2.mydomain.com" default-web-module="app2.war">
       <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
       <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
       <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
       <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
       <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
    [...]
</server>
```

When I try to access, for example, `app1.mydomain.com` the browser correctly redirects to the desired artifact, displaying the application, but missing some images and resources, due the following:

When I was using only one domain (with no virtual server), the root url of the `app1` was `http://app1.mydomain.com/app1` and now is `http://app1.mydomain.com`. So, I want the virtual server to add the context `/app1` again to the application.
Is this possible?